# Animations in Python

Tags: python, data-science

I am running this animation code example in vs code but animations are not running used in the code. Can I have to install extension in vs code?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
import numpy as np

x = []
y = []
colors = []
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))

def animation_func(i):
    x.append(random.randint(0,100))
    y.append(random.randint(0,100))
    colors.append(np.random.rand(1))
    area = random.randint(0,30) * random.randint(0,30)
    plt.xlim(0,100)
    plt.ylim(0,100)
    plt.scatter(x, y, c = colors, s = area, alpha = 0.5)

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animation_func,
                        interval = 100)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code in PyCharm with packages Matplotlib, numpy and pyqt5. The animation worked in this setup.

Make sure you have these packages properly installed in your environment. And I would higly suggest you use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) instead of VsCode.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your code into cells using `# %%`. Running code this way, Visual Studio Code opens an **Interactive pane** that displays the animation.

```
# %%
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
import numpy as np

# %%
x = []
y = []
colors = []
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,5))

def animation_func(i):
    x.append(random.randint(0,100))
    y.append(random.randint(0,100))
    colors.append(np.random.rand(1))
    area = random.randint(0,30) * random.randint(0,30)
    plt.xlim(0,100)
    plt.ylim(0,100)
    plt.scatter(x, y, c = colors, s = area, alpha = 0.5)

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, animation_func,
                        interval = 100)
plt.show()
```

OR

If you want to save the animation then ,

```
...
plt.show()
animation.save("out.gif", writer='pillow')
```